# Sonar Analysis of website before deployment

Tags: apache, jenkins, continuous-integration

I currently have a website (consisting only of static files) and have currently automated the deployment of the website when changes are pushed to the master branch by using a Jenkins multibranch pipeline.

I'm planning to add an extra set of validations before deployment, and I've come across [Sonar](https://github.com/sonarwhal/sonar). Sonar can't be run on static files on its own; it requires these files to be served by a web server such as Apache2, because it also verifies HTTP headers.

Consequently, as long as my changes are not deployed in production, I will not be able to run Sonar on a particular development branch, and would have to wait until the branch is merged into master to obtain the results.

In this case, can you please give hints on how I can get validations results before deployment?

Answer (score 0):

I would setup a Test environment on another machine. It should mirror your production environment as close as possible. Publish to there first. Run Sonar. If all checks out, then deploy to prod. This is a basic Continuous Deployment scenario.

Comment: That's what I first thought of; however, to have a test environment similar to the production one, I need to have similar config files. Is it a common practice to mix website data with webserver config in the same repo? Or maybe use a different repo for the config?

Comment: I have seen it done both ways. The config to setup the environment might be best managed by puppet, but it all depends on how you draw your lines between what is app and what is infrastructure. I personally prefer keeping the webserver config with the application and then use some kind of templating or other mechanism to set or adjust the config based on the environment.